# VB.NET Create two column CheckboxList

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

My below code pulls in 100 items into the checkboxlist all into one column. 
How can I modify the code so it will appear as two columns? Thanks!

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(ImagePath)
        Dim imageArray As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        Dim image As IO.FileInfo

        'list the names of all images in the specified directory

        For Each image In imageArray.OrderBy(Function(i) i.Name)
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is CheckBoxList1? what type of container etc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<asp:checkboxlist id="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="table" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `RepeatDirection`, `RepeatColumns`, and `RepeatLayout`:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatLayout="Table" ...>
```